# Get time a button is clicked, store it in the database then display on page in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, time

This is a bit of a large question I know. I am building a website in the MERN stack- and I want to be able to have a user click a button "checking in" and then have the time that they clicked stored in the database. Then in the React component display the time that was logged from the button click.

the node.js part of the question is the part I am stuck on. how would you suggest I do this?

what I have

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) =>{});
```

I really have no clue where to start.. any help would be appreciated! a general idea would be helpful or documentation that points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the time the user checked in when they click on the check-in button, you can use the in-built javascript Date function to get the current date and time.

In the onCLick method from the frontend, you can grab the current time by declaring a new Date variable like:

`var timeCheckedIn = new Date()`

then you can send `timeCheckedIn` to the API

In your API, you can accept the time via the object or form data you're sending to the API like:

`router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
 const { timeCheckedIn } = req.body
});`

you can read more on using expressJS to handle the body of a request [here](https://expressjs.com/)

To display the date stored in the database, that will also depend on how you're retrieving the data from the server.

you can try the above to see if it helps